# Align text right asp:changepassword

Tags: c#, asp.net, css, alignment, change-password

I use the `<asp:changepassword />` control but I can't figure out how I can align the new password text and the other fields to the left instead of right. I already tried to add a class and do `text-align: left`, but the align remains on the right.

Is it possible to align left?

```
<asp:changepassword id="ChangePassword1" CssClass="teste" runat="server" continuedestinationpageurl="index.aspx"
                oncancelbuttonclick="ChangePassword1_CancelButtonClick" onsendingmail="PasswordRecovery1_SendingMail"
                changepasswordtitletext=" ">
                <ChangePasswordButtonStyle CssClass="botaoAccaoBlue passwordbuttonsfix"  />
                <ContinueButtonStyle CssClass="botaoAccaoBlue passwordbuttonsfix"  />
                <CancelButtonStyle CssClass="botaoAccaoGray passwordbuttonsfix" />
            </asp:changepassword>
```

And this on PageLoad:

```
ChangePassword1.ChangePasswordButtonText = Resources.Common.ResourceManager.GetString("ChangePassword", culture);        
    ChangePassword1.CancelButtonText = Resources.Common.ResourceManager.GetString("Cancel", culture);
    ChangePassword1.PasswordLabelText = Resources.UserConst.ResourceManager.GetString("Password", culture);        
    ChangePassword1.ConfirmNewPasswordLabelText = Resources.Common.ResourceManager.GetString("ConfirmPassword", culture);
    ChangePassword1.NewPasswordLabelText = Resources.Communication.ResourceManager.GetString("New", culture) + " " + Resources.UserConst.ResourceManager.GetString("Password", culture);
```

Comment: Posting your code would be ... helpful.

Comment: Instead of class try applying it to the id `#changepassword {text-align: left !important;}`

Comment: Why do you want to change the text-alignment of the control? Don't do this if you're trying for RTL-language compatibility because that's another property entirely.

Comment: The Souvik solution didn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<asp:ChangePassword LabelStyle-HorizontalAlign="Justify"></asp:ChangePassword>
```

Answer (score 1):

A more details approach would be this
You can start off by looking at this. All the ASP Controls have templates that can be edited
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178339.aspx

Just a basic idea would be like this

```
<asp:changepassword ID="ChangePassword1" runat="server" >
    <ChangePasswordTemplate>
      <table>
        <tr>
          <td>
               Your Textbox control for which you can set the text align property
          </td>
        </tr>
      </table>
   </ChangePasswordTemplate>
</asp:changepassword>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a couple choices.

(1)  This controls has a set of properties called **Style that you can use to adjust the styles of various elements.  For example, to change the alignment of the labels, you might do this...

```
<asp:ChangePassword runat="server">
    <LabelStyle HorizontalAlign="Left" />
</asp:ChangePassword>
```

(2) This control is templated.  If you want more control, you can supply your own markup for the control and let style it any way you like.

Answer (score 0):

After reading your question and attempts to solve the issue, what I understand is you are trying to debug the front end issue from the back end.

When you render a web page, the browser does the UI generation aspect for you from what you set as the parameters on the server. For future activities, when you have UI issues, you problem solution generally will be a CSS solution. MS has tools that will enable you to change CSS from the controls itself, but they are not always what you desire them to be!

A CSS solution to your issue would be: `#ChangePassword1{text-align: left !important;}`